# Which of these differenced datasets is stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality, differencing

I'm working with this [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theadammurphy/h2o_articles/main/time_series/elecequip.csv) from [Forecasting: Principles and Practice 2nd Edition](https://otexts.com/fpp2/). It is clearly not stationary due to the seasonal component.

I have performed 3-month, 9-month, and 12-month differencing and am not sure if any of them are stationary. Stationary data cannot have any seasonal trend (since then the data will depend on time).

[image]

It seems like the 3-month and 9-month plots cannot be stationary due to the regular peaks/troughs. The 12-month plot looks similar to the original data but with big seasonal spikes removed.

Therefore, we conclude that 3-month and 9-month are non-stationary, and 12-month is stationary. Correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's one definition that's considered THE DEFINITION but be careful about the definition of stationarity. The definitions I'm familiar with ( I have two in mind that are slightly different called weak and strong )  don't necessarily get adversely effected by peaks and valleys. But I'll leave the definitions to you because I'm not familiar with that book so it might be defined  differently there so that seasonality could matter. Others may have more useful things to say.

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot about the different definitions. How would you class the above plots based on the definitions you know?

Comment: Are you sure seasonal differencing is a good idea for this time series? If the series does not have a seasonal unit root to begin with, applying a seasonal difference will lead to overdifferencing and its negative implications.

Comment: @RichardHardy No, I am not sure that seasonal differencing is a good idea. I assumed that, since it has a seasonal component, it would be a good idea to apply it.

Comment: Presence of a seasonal component does not necessitate or justify seasonal differencing. Presence of a seasonal unit root (a much rarer phenomenon) does.

Comment: Hi Adam: 3 would pass a test. 12 wouldn't I don't think. Original and 9 I couldn't say off the top of my head. Note though that even two " stationarity tests" can result in different conclusions, particularly if their nulls are different. The whole topic of "testing for stationarity" came out of the unit root problem and it's very much an academic by product. If you're trying to estimate or predict something, you gotta play around a lot with the data and see what works best. There are no hard and fast rules even though the textbooks-papers make it seem that way.

Comment: @mlofton I tested them using ADF. All had p-values ≤0.05 but 3&9 had p-values <0.01. Good point about playing around to see what works in practice. I was writing a time series tutorial and perhaps got a bit stuck in the theory.

Comment: @Adam Murphy: Yes, the theory is beautiful but, in practice, things are different. I'm glad to help.